# process builder with redirecterrorstream hangs in readline

Tags: java, processbuilder

I would like to run a hidden script file that resides in the current location using process builder. with the following code

```
// System.out.println("line"+reader.readLine());
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(shfile.getAbsolutePath());  
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);  
Process process = builder.start();  
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));  
String output = null;  
System.out.println("out");  //===printing this
while (null != (output = br.readLine()))
{  
    System.out.println("in");   //not printing this
    System.out.println(">>"+output);   
}  
int  rs = process.waitFor();
```

but it hangs in the br.readline()..
but when I run the same script file using the following command in terminal

```
sh .script.sh
```

it executes and gives me the expected results

I looked into all the loops in the forum everyone asks to handle input stream and error stream in threads or do a redirect error stream. I have added a redirect error stream but still it hangs.

when i press ctrl+c it prints the initial lines of the output and exits.
Content of my script file

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/ats/cloudripper/lke_factory_asb_v2/lk_assets_factory_release/
sh ./LKE_run_Diablo.sh 0a0e0c3dc893
```

So how to handle this situation.

Comment: Try this:  new ProcessBuilder("sh", shfile.getAbsolutePath())

Comment: still the same behavious it gets stuck at br.readline(). Pressing ctrl+c gives the output

Comment: What is he content of your sh file?

Comment: update in question please look into it

Comment: Replace your "sh ./LKE_run_Diablo.sh 0a0e0c3dc893" for ls (for example), and check that the program exists with the listing. In this case, once you know your code is ok, then you must check what is the "sh ./LKE_run_Diablo.sh 0a0e0c3dc893" doing. Probably the process never print anything or never exits until you press a key or CRTL+c

Comment: Does this make a difference? After start add: `try(OutputStream os = p.getOutputStream()) { }`. This may help if the script is waiting on input.

Answer (score 0):

Process builder have special API to redirect child process input, output and error streams. See [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)
If you need both child and parent process to use same console you should use INHERIT mode redirection. An example:

```
public class ChildProcessOutputProxy {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("whoami");
        builder.redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT);
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);  
        try {
            var child = builder.start();
            child.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }  
    }
    
}
```